# Add prefix to WordPress permalinks

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I am building a plugin to add multi-language support to WordPress.

I need to be able to add language info to the url, and the standard (and sensible) way of doing so is to add the language code as a prefix to the path.

So for example, an English page on the site might be at http://example.com/en/pagename/, whilst a Spanish page might be at http://example.com/es/nombredepagina/.

In order to do this, it is necessary (or rather, desirable, since this can also be done with complex hacks) to modify the WordPress permalink structure so that a language code (consisting, at its most basic form, of 2-3 letters) in the first segment of the path will be used to populate a `lang` query var, whilst the rest of the permalink will still be interpreted as normal.

Is this possible? Sit seems that it should be, but I am not at all familiar with the permalink API and am having trouble figuring it out. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try posting this question on Wordpress.stackexhange.com, or you can search for the question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Add+prefix+to+WordPress+permalinks  lots of similar results.

Comment: Thanks @ckpepper02. I ended up doing something different, but I will look at this in the future and try the WordPress SE. I had thought it was more for questions about *using* WP as opposed to *programming* for it.